# Implementing an AppContext as a Play plugin

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework, inversion-of-control, playframework-1.x

In a Play 1.x application, I'd like to create a class called AppContext, which would serve as a glue layer, between the services in the app. It can play as a simple dependency injector, but I also want it to control the worklfow of events, catching events from the different layers, so that services would not have to do that themselves.

I found that implementing the AppContext as a Plugin would be the best option because it will be able to do some stuff at the time when the application gets loaded, also listen to some events, take some action asynchronously, etc.

Is this the right way to go?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implements this class, AppContext, as wrapper to specific Cache entries and use a distribuited Cache handler (already configurable, as memcache, ehcache, HazelCast, ...).

```java
public class AppContext {
    public String getConfig(String name) {
        return Cache.get("appcontext.config."+name, String.class);
    }

    public void setConfig(String name, String value) {
         Cache.set("appcontext.config."+name, value);
    }

    ...
}
```

There is already several plugin and simply configuration some of this "distributed cache manager", as memcache, eh-cache, Hazelcast.

Alternatively you can use directly Hazelcast (or others) to preserve and synchronize in-memory context and/or to handle queue, data-store, etc. in distributed fashion.